# How to fix "ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘....’"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to install the 'celldex' package from bioconductor but keep getting a non-zero exit status.

I have the latest versions of R, RStudio, annd bioconductor installed (on MacOS). I'm having the same problem with one other bioconductor package, but I haven't run into this issue with any other. I have restarted RStudio, checked for dependencies, but it still won't work. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Here is the command I run:

`BiocManager::install('celldex')`

And I keep getting the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘celldex’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘bit64’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘celldex’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/celldex’

Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘celldex’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the "bit64" package from CRAN? I.e. run `install.packages("bit64")` then restart R and run `BiocManager::install('celldex')` again

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot ! I did so and then had to install 5 other packages and now it works.